# Access an input file from vault template injector

Tags: kubernetes, go-templates, vault

I use Vault to retrieve some secrets that I put inside a configuration file. All works fine until this configuration gets bigger and I want it to be saved in sub configs in a folder. The issue is that those files can't get imported using go templating used to fill passwords..

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  ...
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-init-first: "true"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: "true"
        vault.hashicorp.com/secret-volume-path-my-config: "/my-path/etc"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-file-my-config: "my-app.conf"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-my-config: secret/data/my-app/config
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-my-config: |
          {{- $file := .Files }}
          {{ .Files.Get "configurations/init.conf" }}
          {{- with secret "secret/data/my-app/config" -}}
          ...
          {{- end }}
```

The file `configurations/init.conf` for example doesn't seem to be visible by the vault injector and so gets simply replaced by `<no value>`. Is there a way to make those files in `configurations/*` visible to vault injector maybe by mounting them somewhere?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I'm using a RKE (rancher) provisioned cluster but this can be reproduced with minikube for example, version v1.21.9. Vault in the other hand is a managed instance. Hope this helps